# Is it possible to get another Craft's webApp from within a Craft plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, bootstrap-craft

I have two instances of Craft on the same server. From within a plugin controller in Craft #1, I want to be able to get entries from Craft #2. Can this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed... this will do it:

```
$craft = require '../other/craft/app/bootstrap.php';
$entry = $craft->entries->getEntryById($id);

echo 'Other Craft install entry title:'.$entry->title;
```

Comment: Because: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare craft_createFolder() (previously declared in /path/to/second/craft/app/bootstrap.php:30) in /path/to/first/craft/app/bootstrap.php on line 52

Comment: Well... I did say it was untested. :) I think that should work, though, so that's a potential bug.  Will look into it.

Comment: Cool. I'm in a bit of a hurry, though, so will use a workaround for now.

Comment: I supposed I went back and fixed this at one point because it works now. :)